# LE Connection-Oriented Channels - Android support

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

[Here](https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth/services#bluetooth-low-energy-features) is stated that Android 8.0 supports LE Connection-Oriented Channels. However I don't see any reference of it in the Android API. The `BluetoothAdapter` [class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html) only has only methods for listening RFCOMM sockets (which runs on BT Classic only); and the `BluetoothSocket` [class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html) says: *"The most common type of Bluetooth socket is RFCOMM, which is the type supported by the Android APIs."*

How is possible to use LE CoC? Can someone help to clarify this confusion? Moreover is seems they are supported by the BLE stack that runs below the Java API, see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/master/stack/include/l2c_api.h#455) for example.

Comment: L2CAP CoC will be supported starting from Android Q. I'm not able to cite official sources about that

Answer (score 1):

LE L2CAP Connection Oriented Channel Support is a new introduced feature at core spec 4.1.

After reviewed the android 8.0 code(I did not test CoC feature since it need remote device also support CoC), from the code perspective you should able to use this feature at Android 8.0.

Let's assume you want to connect socket act as a client at Phone side, you do not need call RFCOMM socket but call L2CAP, use following socket [API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html);
Note that two items need mentioned:
1) Use the TYPE_L2CAP when init the socket structure.
2) Apply the CoC mask(0x20000) when set the socket port.

Here is the JNI link: [JNI](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/packages/apps/Bluetooth/jni/com_android_bluetooth_btservice_AdapterService.cpp#connectSocketNative)

Here is the stack link: [stack](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/system/bt/btif/src/btif_sock.cc#btsock_connect)

Under [Here](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/system/bt/btif/src/btif_sock_l2cap.cc#975) you will find the socket link to L2CAP connections.

Line #912 on this [page](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/system/bt/btif/src/btif_sock_l2cap.cc#btsock_l2cap_listen_or_connect) indicate the CoC format.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have a CoC device either; I will get one next week. I was trying to find a link between the BLE stack code and the Java API you mentioned but I failed; do you have any insight on that?

Comment: You might find following links which may help you how the logic goes:

Comment: @GuoXingmin am I getting it right that these APIs can only be accessed via NDK or reflection?

Comment: @GuoXingmin yes, I see that there are methods to get an instance of a BluetoothSocket with type=L2CAP, but they have the `@hide` annotation

Comment: e.g.: the `createL2capSocket` method in the `BluetoothDevice` class

Comment: Please see (and hopefully contradict) my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614736/how-can-i-instantiate-a-l2cap-socket-in-android