# Android 10 L2CAP connection IOException timeout Wii Balance Board

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-10.0, l2cap, wii-balanceboard

### Background

A long time ago I was tasked with making a android app for the Wii Balance Board, after some screwing around I found that android no longer supported L2CAP. More [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614736/how-can-i-instantiate-a-l2cap-socket-in-android) lead to understand that it was being re-added in Android 10. With Android 10 out I've been trying to give it a crack now.

### Problem

So my simple goal at the moment is to create a connection with the Wii Balance Board.

My approach for connection is:

- Start discovery
- Add discovered bluetooth devices to list
- When you click on a device it then tries to open a socket as such:

  `bluetoothSocket = btDevice.createInsecureL2capChannel(port);`
- As mentioned on the [WiiBrew](https://wiibrew.org/wiki/Wiimote) site I'm using psm value 0x13 for input and 0x11 for output.
- I then use `bluetoothSocket.connect` and proceed to receive a IOException (timeout error)
- I've also tried using both `createL2capChannel` and `createInsecureL2capChannel` with same results
- I was able to successfully pair to the device using `btDevice.createBond()` and then using the phones BT address backwards for `.setpin()` and the Wii Balance Board simply acts as a "dumb" input device. (not sure if pairing is needed/good idea)

The above is a simplified flow of how I'm trying to connect. I've also tried using `BalanceBoard.java` from Paul Burton's [fitscales](https://github.com/paulburton/fitscales) repo updating all of the old bluetooth code, again I still get the timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the bt_stack logs?

Here is mine from trying to open a socket with a wiimote:

```
04-05 12:25:04.949 E/bt_stack(4895): [ERROR:btif_sock_l2cap.cc(244)] SOCK_LIST: free(id = 4) - NO app_fd!
04-05 12:25:04.949 I/bt_stack(4895): [INFO:btsnoop.cc(323)] clear_l2cap_whitelist: Clearing whitelist from l2cap channel. conn_handle=65535 cid=65:0
04-05 12:25:04.949 E/bt_l2cap(4895): L2CA_FreeLePSM: Invalid PSM=19 value!
04-05 12:25:40.141 I/bt_stack(4895): [INFO:btsnoop.cc(323)] clear_l2cap_whitelist: Clearing whitelist from l2cap channel. conn_handle=1 cid=66:64
04-05 12:25:55.736 I/bt_stack(4895): [INFO:btsnoop.cc(323)] clear_l2cap_whitelist: Clearing whitelist from l2cap channel. conn_handle=2 cid=67:65
```

I believe this is where the problem lies, Im only a novice so Im not sure what can be done about it. I know the old ways of connecting passed the fd as a parameter to the bluetooth socket constructor but I dont think this is possible anymore

Comment: FYI, the invalid PSM value error is generated in this file: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/master/stack/l2cap/l2c_api.cc, and the PSM range is limited from 0x80 to 0xFF. The range constants are in this file: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/refs/heads/master/stack/l2cap/l2c_int.h, you can see them defined as LE_DYNAMIC_PSM_START and LE_DYNAMIC_PSM_END.