# Bluetooth HID in Android (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth, hid

I have a Wii remote and I want to connect it to my android phone with just Java if possible. I have tried to look for libraries and other things like that but there was nothing. I am new to Bluetooth development, I don't know how it works entirely. Other than that, I would love to get some links on how to connect a Bluetooth device as an HID and send data to a specific address. Thank you all!!!!

Comment: Are you asking about Bluetooth HID or are you asking [Is it possible to use a wiimote as an android game controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61029057/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang I was asking if I could connect the Wiimote to my android phone. Thank you so much for the link!!